# Slider transparente sem fundo

Tags: slider, background

Como fazer um slider com o fundo transparente, sem ter que baixar a opacidade do slider no mínimo? Gostaria do slider utilizando somente o background do site enquanto as figuras passam.

Comment: Tens que dar mais informação que isso, em que língua, o que é que já tentaste, quanto mais informação deres melhor mas sem meter informação irrelevante. O stackoverflow serve para te ajudar e não para fazer o trabalho por ti, não podes simplesmente meter um pedido sem tentares fazer tu. Não tenhas medo de editar a tua pergunta para meter mais informação. E se bem vindo :)

Comment: Ao que me parece vc quer uma imagem sem fundo dentro do slider, assim o background do site pode aparecer por de traz da imagem do slider. Para resolver isso vc vai ter que tirar o fudo das imagens do slider no PhotoShop ou outro software do tipo e salvar essa imagem como PNG ou GIF, pois são formatos que aceitam transparência na imagem.